# How to perform encoding and syndrome measurement in stim

Tags: programming, error-correction, stabilizer-code, stim

I can generate the encoding circuit of a stabilizer code and can read it into
[stim](https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim). For example for the $[[5,1,3]]$ code :

```
 circuit=stim.Circuit()
 circuit.append_operation("H",[1])
 circuit.append_operation("CY",[0,4])
 circuit.append_operation("H",[2])
 circuit.append_operation("CX",[1,4])
 circuit.append_operation("H",[3])
 circuit.append_operation("CZ",[2,0])
 circuit.append_operation("CZ",[2,1])
 circuit.append_operation("CX",[2,4])
 circuit.append_operation("H",[4])
 circuit.append_operation("CZ",[3,0])
 circuit.append_operation("CZ",[3,2])
 circuit.append_operation("CY",[3,4])
```

To check this I'd like to encode a random qubit then measure the syndrome for the 4 stabilizers; if everything is correct the syndrome should always be $(0,0,0,0)$.

First step : the "data" qubit is placed on qubit 4 (numbering starts from 0). So the input to
the encoder is $(q0=0,q1=0,q2=0,q3=0,q4=d0)$. $k=1$ for this code so there's only one data qubit.
How would I initialize the input to be of that form?

Second step : I have 4 stabilizers which are just Pauli strings of length 5. I'd like to measure the syndromes and place the result on 4 ancilla qubits. How would I do that and then check that the syndromes are 0?

Comment: Are the measurements assumed to be noiseless?

Comment: @CraigGidney yes for now

Comment: You can get a more succinct program for the circuit via `print(repr(circuit))`, by the way.

Comment: the circuit is automatically generated by a program but I'll try the more concise syntax later

Comment: Oh you're using code generation to generate the python code that generates the stim circuit. A bit indirect compared to just generating the circuit but it'll work.

Comment: I use other languages to generate the stabilizers. Once I have these I use the same languages to generate python/stim low level circuits. This scales better for more complicated codes (100's of qubits...). Unfortunately I'm now stuck since I don't know how to initialize the input of the circuit in stim.

Comment: The input is the logical qubit's state? You can use observable swapping to get it into the system. https://algassert.com/post/1717

Comment: Isn't the input to any encoder circuit a state of certain form? How would you "encode" otherwise? Here the encoder should map $(0,0,0,0,d)$ to $(c_0,c_1,c_2,c_3,c_4)$ where $c$ is fixed by all the stabilizers and $d$ can be recovered from $c$ through a decoding operation.  What was your approach for the repetition or honeycomb codes?

Comment: In fault tolerant codes for doing computation you always directly initialize into logical single qubit stabilizer states and then get other places via operations. Otherwise it's not fault tolerant end to end. This is typically transversal; in the honeycomb code to initialize logical |0> or logical |+> I just set all the qubits to |0> or |+> accordingly, and then start running the measurement cycle. Your case may be more like a communication code, where you have some unprotected physical qubit that you want to get into the code without protection *then* noise turns on.

Comment: even in your case you have to set the qubits to a certain pattern. Let's pick the all $0$ case, what would be the stim syntax?

Comment: the initialization is literally `R 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 ...` for logical 0 or `RX 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 ...` for logical plus.

Comment: Appendix D of the paper ( https://arxiv.org/abs/2108.10457 ) has the complete 2x6 honeycomb circuit as a stim circuit.

Comment: I should be able to work with that. I'll also try to run the honeycomb example from the appendix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `MPP` instruction to measure a Pauli product. For example, if one of the prepared stabilizers is $X_1 \cdot Z_2 \cdot Y_3 = +1$ then you can do:

```
# [... encoding circuit ... ]

# measure stabilizer
MPP X1*Z2*Y3
# and claim it's supposed to have a deterministic result
DETECTOR rec[-1]
```

If you now sample the detectors of the circuit via `circuit.compile_detector_sampler().sample(shots=10)` you should get back a numpy array filled with 0s, indicating the system has been prepared into an eigenstate of the stabilizer. If you instead see a 50/50 mix of 0s and 1s, something is wrong.

The next step would be to do that for each stabilizer, and then add noise and confirm that you see the stabilizers flipping:

```
# [... encoding circuit ... ]

# phase damp qubit 3, potentially flipping the stabilizer
Z_ERROR(0.1) 3

# measure stabilizer
MPP X1*Z2*Y3
# and claim it's supposed to have a deterministic result
DETECTOR rec[-1]
```

Beware that adding `Z 3` is *not* the same thing as adding `Z_ERROR(1) 3`. Detectors compute what the expected value is supposed to be, and report deviations from that value arising from noise. `Z 3` is part of the expected value calculation, whereas `Z_ERROR(1) 3` is part of the noise.

You can use `MPP(wrong_result_probability)` to make the measurement result itself noisy (with no effect on the qubits).

You may also want to decompose the compound measurement into some underlying gateset, and make each of the individual operations noisy. Stim won't do that for you, but you can of course tell it the decomposed measurement's circuit as well as the noise mechanism instructions around each of its pieces.

Comment: What about the initialization part? the first 4 qubits have to be in state 0. Also how would I place the syndrome values on ancilla qubits? this would be needed for decoding later

Comment: @unknown Why would you want the syndrome stored in qubits instead of stored in the measurement record? If your measurements are noiseless the distinction between decomposing it into a form using an ancilla and a form not using an ancilla is irrelevant.

Comment: you might have a point there...i'll revisit when I get to the decoding part

Answer (score 0):

I was able to setup the encoding and syndrome check for the example $[[5,1,3]]$ code.

```
import stim
circuit=stim.Circuit('''
RZ 0 1 2 3
RZ 4

H 0
CY 0 4
H 1
CX 1 4
H 2
CZ 2 0
CZ 2 1
CX 2 4
H 3
CZ 3 0
CZ 3 2
CY 3 4

MPP Y0*Z1*Z3*Y4 X1*Z2*Z3*X4 Z0*Z1*X2*X4 Z0*Z2*Y3*Y4

''')
sampler = circuit.compile_sampler()
print(sampler.sample(shots=8))
```

The results :

```
[[1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1]
 [1 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 1]]
```

The results for the second and third stabilizers are ok (always 0).
The first and fourth stabilizers have a problem; they should also be 0.
This is the encoded 0 state. The encoded 1 state is what you would get if you change the second line in the circuit from RZ 4 to RX 4. The problem happens in both cases. I think the problem might be related to the $Y$ gate; the problem stabilizers have it the ones that are ok do not. "My" $Y$ gate is just $XZ$ not $\imath XZ$ so it's orthogonal and unitary but not hermitian. I have my reasons to stay with this convention. Is there way to work with the real (not complex) version of $Y$ in stim; this might solve the problem.

Fixed circuit : (replaces CY with CX and CZ) :

```
import stim
circuit=stim.Circuit('''
RZ 0 1 2 3
RX 4

H 0
CX 0 4
CZ 0 4
H 1
CX 1 4
H 2
CZ 2 0
CZ 2 1
CX 2 4
H 3
CZ 3 0
CZ 3 2
CX 3 4
CZ 3 4

MPP Y0*Z1*Z3*Y4 X1*Z2*Z3*X4 Z0*Z1*X2*X4 Z0*Z2*Y3*Y4

''')
sampler = circuit.compile_sampler()
print(sampler.sample(shots=8))
```

With stim 1.9 these two tests give different results :

```
def TstOk():
 circuit=stim.Circuit()
 circuit.append_operation("RZ",[0,1,2,3]);
 circuit.append_operation("RX",[4]);
 circuit.append_operation("H",[0])
 circuit.append_operation("CX",[0,4])
 circuit.append_operation("CZ",[0,4])
 circuit.append_operation("H",[1])
 circuit.append_operation("CX",[1,4])
 circuit.append_operation("H",[2])
 circuit.append_operation("CZ",[2,0])
 circuit.append_operation("CZ",[2,1])
 circuit.append_operation("CX",[2,4])
 circuit.append_operation("H",[3])
 circuit.append_operation("CZ",[3,0])
 circuit.append_operation("CZ",[3,2])
 circuit.append_operation("CX",[3,4])
 circuit.append_operation("CZ",[3,4])
 circuit.append_operation("MPP",[
    stim.target_y(0),stim.target_combiner(), stim.target_z(1),stim.target_z(3),stim.target_combiner(), stim.target_y(4),
    stim.target_x(1),stim.target_combiner(), stim.target_z(2),stim.target_z(3),stim.target_combiner(), stim.target_x(4),
    stim.target_z(0),stim.target_combiner(), stim.target_z(1),stim.target_x(2),stim.target_combiner(), stim.target_x(4),
    stim.target_z(0),stim.target_combiner(), stim.target_z(2),stim.target_y(3),stim.target_combiner(), stim.target_y(4)
 ])
 sampler = circuit.compile_sampler()
 print(sampler.sample(shots=8))
```

results :

```
[[False False False False False False  True  True]
 [False False False  True  True False False  True]
 [ True  True  True  True False False  True  True]
 [ True  True False False  True  True  True  True]
 [False False  True  True  True  True  True  True]
 [False False False  True  True False  True False]
 [ True  True False  True False  True False  True]
 [False False  True False False  True False  True]]
```

"bas test"

```
def TstNotOk():
 circuit=stim.Circuit('''
 RZ 0 1 2 3
 RX 4
 H 0
 CX 0 4
 CZ 0 4
 H 1
 CX 1 4
 H 2
 CZ 2 0
 CZ 2 1
 CX 2 4
 H 3
 CZ 3 0
 CZ 3 2
 CX 3 4
 CZ 3 4
 MPP Y0*Z1*Z3*Y4 X1*Z2*Z3*X4 Z0*Z1*X2*X4 Z0*Z2*Y3*Y4
 ''')
 sampler = circuit.compile_sampler()
 print(sampler.sample(shots=8))
```

results are always all False

```
[[False False False False]
 [False False False False]
 [False False False False]
 [False False False False]
 [False False False False]
 [False False False False]
 [False False False False]
 [False False False False]]
```

Comment: You shouldn't use X*Z instead of Y in your stabilizers because it has imaginary eigenvalues. It's not Hermitian. It's not an observable. That being said, as long as you always use two of them the imaginaries combine into a negation, flipping the measurement result. You can account for that with a `!` like `MPP !Y0*Z1*Z3*Y4`. But it actually looks like something more serious is wrong, because you're seeing varying values. I think you haven't correctly prepared the state.

Comment: Another thing you can do to help with this problem is to use DETECTORs. Add `DETECTOR rec[-4]` through `DETECTOR rec[-1]` at the end of your circuit and then `compile_detector_sampler()` instead of `compile_sampler()`. The benefit is that detectors figure out if the associated measurement is supposed to be true or false, and tell you when it deviates from that, so you only have to care about getting your circuit correct up to Paulis. E.g. you don't have to pay attention to things like "did I use an S gate instead of an inverse S gate"; the detectors make it work.

Comment: The way I define the codes $Y=XZ$ is much nicer to work with (everything is real and orthogonal). I found a fix for the problem : I changed CY a b to CX a b CZ a b. The syndrome check works now

Comment: I re-emphasize the dangers of working with "observables" or "stabilizers" that are not Hermitian. X*Z has real entries but its eigenvalues are imaginary. I'll assume you know what you're doing, but be very careful. You will be performing unitary operations on your system when you "measure" those.

Comment: Here's a concrete example. Repeatedly projecting the "observable" X*Z is not idempotent: https://algassert.com/quirk#circuit=%7B%22cols%22:[[%22H%22],[%22Amps1%22],[],[1,1,%22H%22],[%22Z%22,1,%22%E2%80%A2%22],[%22X%22,1,%22%E2%80%A2%22],[1,1,%22H%22],[%22Amps1%22,1,%22|0%E2%9F%A9%E2%9F%A80|%22],[],[1,1,%22H%22],[%22Z%22,1,%22%E2%80%A2%22],[%22X%22,1,%22%E2%80%A2%22],[1,1,%22H%22],[%22Amps1%22,1,%22|0%E2%9F%A9%E2%9F%A80|%22],[],[1,1,%22H%22],[%22Z%22,1,%22%E2%80%A2%22],[%22X%22,1,%22%E2%80%A2%22],[1,1,%22H%22],[%22Amps1%22,1,%22|0%E2%9F%A9%E2%9F%A80|%22]]%7D

Comment: I'll definitely keep that in mind. I should be able to convert my "real" codes to ones where $Y$ is hermitian; shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: @CraigGidney this used to work back in October; with stim 1.9 the result is an 8x4 array of "False" instead of the expected binary matrix...what changed?

Comment: I updated the dtype from np.uint8 to np.bool8 which causes it to print False/True instead of 0/1. But when I run the code it still return the same data; there are True entries where the 1s were. You're saying you don't have any Trues? That sounds serious; report it as a bug for sure. BTW If you want 0s and 1s back you can use np.ndarray.astype(np.uint8) to convert it. dtype=np.bool8 is the "correct" type because it's boolean data. which is why I changed it.

Comment: @CraigGidney the "fixed" (second) version prints all "False"; the original has some "True" values but very different from the result. I'll see if I can report it as bug...at github or somewhere else?

Comment: at github.com/quantumlib/stim

Comment: I am also seeing that the second version prints all False, but v1.8 and v1.7 and v1.6 of stim it prints all 0s so that seems consistent over time.

Comment: I didn't keep track of which version I ran in October, but for the first do you get exactly  [[1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1]
 [1 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 1]]  (True/False equivalent)

Comment: No, but you're not supposed to get EXACTLY that. You're sampling from a distribution where some of the outputs are random, so the order of the outputs and the exact observed frequency of each output can vary. The key thing is that it's the same distribution, which it appears to be.

Comment: @CraigGidney I edited my answer with what I see

Comment: It would be more productive if this was moved to Stim's github issues, instead of qc exchange comments. Open an issue there: https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/issues/new